# How to convert future::join_all() to using FuturesUnordered?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am making something like below! `function1()` and `function2()` both are doing async steps to insert a large amount of data into the database. However, I think join_all() can't handle too much data. It always stop after I inserted about 1500 data. I saw someone say `FuturesUnordered` is good to handle large operations, but I didn't find any example for it. Is anyone has experience with it? If so, can show to how to convert my code to use `FuturesUnordered`?

```
async fn main() {
    println!("Start to insert data to database!");
    block_on(hold());
}

async fn hold() {
    let futures = vec![function1(),function2()];
    let _results = future::join_all(futures).await;
}
```

Below, is the code I did for `FuturesUnordered`, but not work!

```
async fn main() {
    println!("Start to insert data to database!");
    block_on(hold());
}

async fn hold() {
    let futures = FuturesUnordered::collect（function1(),function2()）;
    let _results = FuturesUnordered::poll(futures).await;
}
```

Comment: Your program likely stops because of a bug. You should investigate the blockage rather than swapping APIs and hoping for a different result.

Answer (score 3):

You can either create it and push tasks to it manually:

```
let futures = FuturesUnordered::new();
futures.push(function1());
futures.push(function2());
```

Or if your tasks are already in an iterable, you can collect into it just like any other collection:

```
let futures: FuturesUnordered<_> = vec![function1(), function2()]
    .into_iter()
    .collect();
```

Then you can simply collect and await the results (`.collect()` provided by [`StreamExt`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html)):

```
let results: Vec<_> = futures.collect().await;
```

See these working on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=827b5b2e6836afdbaeb8acc8e79117ba).

---

I am skeptical that this change will address your root problem though. No use of `join_all` should cause your tasks to run incorrectly, and swapping it for `FuturesUnordered` should only yield a performance difference, and likely not much of one for only two tasks. The [docs](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/future/fn.join_all.html) for `join_all` already say it'll switch to using `FuturesUnordered` internally when there are a large number of tasks, and the [current threshold is set at 30](https://docs.rs/futures-util/0.3.17/src/futures_util/future/join_all.rs.html#35).

Comment: Thank you, you are right! The result is same, there are still stop about 1500 data were insert.

Comment: It's worth noting that `StreamExt` must be in scope for the second `collect()` to work. For some reason the compiler doesn't make this recommendation explicitly right now.

Comment: @LeeAlex did you actually figure out what to do with it? I'm having the same issue now